# Why has this question been downvoted and closed. And how should I improve my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

I asked this question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732370/what-do-we-mean-by-number-of-things. I do not know why it is downvoted. I asked in my comment why the silent downvotes but none has told me the reason(s) yet. It appears to me that I made something inappropriate but what. I want to improve my question. English is not my first language so if the downvotes are due the grammatical or formatting mistakes then please tell me I will improve these things.

**Edit:** The question has been edited to become more direct. Why it is still downvoted? Why it is closed? If it is not about mathematics then to which field it belongs? At which SE site I should post this question? Once I had posted a [similar version](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/20754/3448) of it on English-lang-learners.SE. They said it should be asked on MSE but now it is closed at MSE too.

Comment: Regarding the edit: Why would the downvotes go away due to an edit? And as for reopening: I am not sure if it goes into the reopen queue by being edited unless this is done before "on hold" changes to "closed".

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft , Sergio said that the question was not direct. The downvotes were there because my question was not direct. Since I've made the question more direct the downvotes should go away.

Comment: Sure, and if those people who downvoted (a long time ago) notice the edit and now like the question, they might decide the reverse the vote. There is no automatic script that does this.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The others who think my question is not downvotable should upvote my question to counter the downvotes. If the ones who downvoted my question do not see my edit and no one upvote my question then it will be unjustifiably deleted by the comm mod soon.

Comment: Why should people upvote a question unless they actually feel it deserves an upvote?

Comment: Votes in compensation, either downvotes or upvotes, are explicitely discouraged.

Comment: Enough is enough. I do not like silent downvoting. If some one downvotes then he/she should have guts to point out the mistake/reason. If the downvotes are due to the question being a beginner level they why don't you guys say it explicitly. There is no point in wasting time on political discussions. Thank you every one for your constructive suggestions.

Comment: Contrary to my usual practice,  I explained my downvote in a comment last month: I downvoted your question because you showed a propensity to argue with the replies without trying to understand them and to ask the same questions repeatedly after they had already been answered. That being the case I am not surprised to find you asking again why your question was downvoted without trying to understand the explanation I gave you last month.

Comment: @MJD Thank you for the explanation of your downvote. I will read comments contemplatively in future. By the way now I understand what you were saying in the comments. I should have read rudimentary set theory before arguing with you. Please accept my apologies.

Comment: So the reason for the 4 downvoted is my comments. I see, its a fair reason for the downvotes. Is this the same reason my question is closed? Someone has also voted to delete it. Please do not delete it. Many people has spent their time in writing their answers. I cannot improve what I had done in past but I will keep it in mind next time.

Comment: Your second linked question isn't on a different SE site. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to address the meta related to the site?

Comment: @dustin The second linked question is on a different SE site. That question is fine there, I don't have anything to ask on their meta.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is very long, one reads lots of paragraphs before knowing what are the questions. Math.SE is for **questions** and not **discussions**. Please try to be more direct.

Comment: But if I do not elaborate then it would be unclear. I have highlighted the main points. The extra can be skipped. If the points are not clear one should read the remaining context.

Comment: @Anupam Sometimes less is more. If you elaborate too much, people don't know what you want to ask. For your long question, I can only understand it after reread it the 2.5 times. No, I don't downvote you but you question is definitely not something I wish to upvote.

Comment: I have edited my [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732370/what-do-we-mean-by-the-term-number-of-things). Is it ok now?

Comment: '-1'-- I do not agree with you. [Others say](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960/103816) one should present every minor detail in his/her question ad I agree with that.

Comment: @user31782 The page you link to does not say that "one should present every minor detail".

Comment: @Did By every presenting minor detail I mean presenting: Context, Include your work, provide some motivation to your question, tell us where the question comes from, Indicate your own background, Give full references, Give definitions. After mentioning all this things he question will obviously become large.

Comment: @user31782 Which is obviously not the same thing as "every minor detail". Following these guidelines means including everything *relevant to the question* hence the final text of the question may be long or not.

Comment: @Did Sorry for my wrong usage of English. My [previous comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13260/why-this-question-has-been-downvoted-and-closed-how-should-i-improve-my-questio/13262?noredirect=1#comment54203_13262) is the reason I have downvoted this answer. Regards

Comment: If this is of interest, I think that Sergio's answer (complemented by achille's comment) is exactly to the point.